# how to get profile information for users using google drive api

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to migrate from the Documents List API to Drive API.

My application using "[getting profile information for users](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/?hl=it-IT#getting_profile_information_for_users)" function, but Google Drive API has no that function.

So, I have a problem to migrate from the Documents List API.

Please let'me know how to solve it.

Comment: you can not ger Profile information by Google Drive Api , you should use Google+ api for it

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get

just wrap the function, given on the page and run it , you will get your answer

Answer (score 2):

See:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#userinfocall

for updated information on retrieving user profile information.

Comment: Thanks Jay, but that can't retrieving document updater's profile.