# How to get a Drive.v3.Data.User on drive api c#

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I'm working on a dll with some drive methods and I have all working right now, every method works in a base `Drive.service` i get when the user authentificates.

I finished almost all of my methods unless the personal user data, I'm suposed to get it from `Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.User` which has a few methods that get it to me.

My problem is that i can't create a `Data.User` object who has the user info that has authorized me, I don't know how to get a `Data.User object` that contains the info from a specific user.

Comment: Check this SO question [14445708](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445708/how-to-get-profile-information-for-users-using-google-drive-api?rq=1) and [11304767](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304767/how-to-get-the-owner-of-file-using-google-drive-api?rq=1) if it can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating a PlusService (like the DriveService i was using for drive but for g+)

```
 PlusService service = new PlusService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                            {
                              HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                              ApplicationName = "Google Plus Sample",
                            });
                       return service;
```

for this i needed to add `using Google.Apis.Plus.v1;` and modifie my scope when i get my credential to:
`new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,PlusService.Scope.UserinfoProfile, PlusService.Scope.UserinfoEmail}`

I also needed to enable the g+ api on my google developer console

Once you have the PlusService you need to get an user, i used this to get the user autentified on the credential("me" get's you your current user):

```
Person user =serviceplus.People.Get("me").Execute();
```

With this user you are able to get a lot of information about the user, even his relation status :P

I hope this helps someone